# How are "unique IDs" generated for 1wire devices?

Tags: 1-wire, uuids

(I previously posted this question on the Arduino SE, but it was downvoted as "not Arduino enough", so I post it here in the hope it will be better received.)

If I wanted to make my own 1wire device, I would need to give it a "globally unique" 48-bit identifier.

How are these identifiers generated? How can we guarantee no identifier conflicts with another brand's devices?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a reasonable question.  I am glad to have read the answers!

Comment: In my opinion this question is on-topic here at EE (though I could imagine others seeing it differently). But it's most definitively off-topic on Arduino SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are assigned by Dallas Semiconductor, now a part of Maxim, now a part of Analog Devices. I'm sure there's a way to make them reserve you a family code or an address range within a family code, but this will cost you a fortune.

For a hobby project, I recommend to pick an unused family code from [this list](https://www.owfs.org/index_php_page_family-code-list.html) and do your own bookkeeping. Oh, and please provide an OWFS driver for your device, or contact me on this later on.

Answer (score 5):

1-wire is a proprietary protocol of Dallas Semiconductor (now Analog Devices), which means that they are the only company manufacturing 1-wire devices. Since "1-wire" is a registered trademark, nobody except Analog Device may legally brand a device as being a "1-wire device".

The question of ID assignment coordination therefore doesn't even arise.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire, https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/1wire-devices.html

Comment: That may be true, but at least half a dozen manufacturers have cloned the DS18B20 temperature sensor . Digikey even sells one of them ([UMW](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/2890/UMW%20DS18B20.pdf)), though at a painfully high price relative to the Asia price.

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet for [DS2502-E48 48-Bit Node Address Chip](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DS2502-E48.pdf) contains the following in the features:

> Provides valid MAC-48/EUI-48 Ethernet address

And the following the description:

> The first 32 bytes of the DS2502-E48’s EPROM memory contain a globally unique 48-bit node address  and are **write-protected**.

And shows the following breakdown of the data structure:
[image]

I.e. if you connect a DS2502-E48 it should come with a unique ID.

Comment: All the onewire devices have a unique id themselves. For the DS2502-E48, those unique IDs just also resemble unique Ethernet MACs that Dallas Semi reserved for themselves. If you don't build your own low-volume Ethernet hardware, you don't need those.